# PHPSpreadsheet how to copy cell with formatting?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

can you tell me how to copy the value of a cell and its formatting to another cell?
You have an Excel document (xlsx) where, for example, cell J5 contains the value "positive" with black fill and white text (white text on a black background).
I want to copy this value into cell C2, but no matter how I try (neither getValue, nor getFormattingValue) - only the value is copied, without formatting.

Below is some code that tries different options. By the way, I also noticed that in the resulting file (test_result.xlsx), the formatting for cell J5 disappears altogether.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("test.xlsx");
$links2 = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->getCell("J5")->getValue();
$links3 = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->getCell("J5")->getFormattedValue();
$links4 = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->getCell("J5")->getCalculatedValue();
$spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, 2, $links2);
$spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, 3, $links3);
$spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, 4, $links4);
$oWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$oWriter->save("test_result.xlsx");
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getFormattedValue only transfers the formatting of the cell itself (text, cilo, etc.), but not the styles.
So that you can copy the data into an array and then apply it. Those. the final pseudocode will look something like this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("test.xlsx");
$links2 = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->getCell("J5")->getValue();
$styleArray = $spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->getStyle('J5')->exportArray();
$spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, 2, $links2);
$spreadsheet->getSheet(0)->getStyle('С2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$oWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$oWriter->save("test_result.xlsx");
?>
```